# How to implement database per tenant strategy on ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, multi-tenant, ef-core-3.1

If every tenant has its own database and problem here is how to decide dynamically which connection string needed to be injected and how to make connection strings available.

I have found an article on "Implementing database per tenant strategy on ASP.NET Core" and this explain everything clearly. 
https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-database-per-tenant/

First define new Tenant class

```
public class Tenant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

And we need a separate MasterDb to store tenant configurations. And that means it requires separate DbContext to represent a session with the MasterDb.

```
public class MasterDbContext : DbContext
{
    private DbSet<Tenant> Tenants { get; set; }

    public MasterDbContext(DbContextOptions<MasterDbContext> options) : base(options){}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().HasKey(e => e.Id);
    }

    public Tenant GetTenant(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        Tenant tenant = Tenants.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Host.ToLower() == accessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.Value.ToLower());
        return tenant;
    }
}
```

Now it’s time to bring ITenantProvider and write an implementation that uses MasterDbContext. This provider holds all the logic about detecting host header and getting current tenant.

```
public interface ITenantProvider
{
   Tenant GetTenant();
}

public class TenantProvider : ITenantProvider
{
    private readonly Tenant _tenant;

    public TenantProvider(IHttpContextAccessor accessor,
                                MasterDbContext context)
    {
        _tenant = context.GetTenant(accessor);
    }

    public Tenant GetTenant()
    {
        return _tenant;
    }
}
```

Configuring OrganizationDbContext dynamically.

```
public class OrganizationDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly Tenant _tenant;

    public DbSet<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public OrganizationContext(DbContextOptions<OrganizationContext> options,ITenantProvider tenantProvider): base(options)
    {
        _tenant = tenantProvider.GetTenant();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(_tenant.DatabaseConnectionString);
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Branch>().HasKey(e => e.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasKey(e => e.Id);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) are some best practices on how to ask a question on SO. You should read that.

Comment: Post has been improved. Now what are you ***actually*** trying to achieve and what is the problem you are facing based on what you have tried so far?. With that we can probably get the post reopened.

Comment: Actually, I had no idea of how to inject database connection in run-time when it comes to multi tenancy. First I though I have to write kind of a middleware to inject the connection string. But going through this article, i got some idea to achieve this.  https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-database-per-tenant/

Comment: So in fact the question is answered now?

Comment: Yes, I can dynamically configure DbContext and it injects correct database connection. Hope everything will be okay.

Comment: I have updated my answer in the question itself. [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59519871/12609535)